# prevent insertion of duplicate records to oracle table from R

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I am trying to insert data frame to oracle table. On the Oracle table I have PK set up on Date and LPAR column. I need to prevent insertion of duplicate records into the table.

I have the following code to go through each data frame and insert it inot the table. When I have the fast option set to FALSE, my slqSAVE fails.

Can somebody recommend any other way to prevent insertion of duplicate records and continue on processing the data frame. For example, if one row fails, I need to contiue on processing the remaining rows, etc?

```
tryCatch({
   ch=odbcConnect("<DSN>",pwd = "<password>")
    sqlSave(ch,dat, tablename="<table_name", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE, fast=FALSE)
  },error = function(e) {
    print("error")   })   
odbcClose(ch
```

)

Comment: This is really not an R question, but rather an Oracle SQL question. Please edit your tags.

Comment: Oh all right, I'll do it for you.

Comment: Well, you could just write a stored proc that makes sure the record doesn't exist yet.  You could also create a key that could limit on whatever columns you want to be unique.